# Web Request asynchronous iscompleted

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webrequest

I will be use this.
http://www.matlus.com/httpwebrequest-asynchronous-programming/

But how can I know request iscompleted? So how do I know that the work done?

I use like it :

```
PostAsync(url, postParameters, callbackState =>
{
    if (callbackState.Exception != null)
    {
        throw callbackState.Exception;
    }
    else
    {
        WriteCallBack(GetResponseText(callbackState.ResponseStream));
    }
});
```

But I do not know whether it ends the process?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the "if" line and step through it.

Comment: I want some message box, if process is completed.  I do not know when it will end,

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation it says:

> Each of these methods also requires a callback delegate that is called back with the response of the http call[...] The callback will be called for each response, as and when a response is received and we simply continue on with processing the response as we see fit

Whatever you do with the `callbackState` delegate, it will hold the response content. That's how you know it will be finished.

Edit: Example from the docs.

```
      ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 50;
      var url = "http://localhost/HttpTaskServer/default.aspx";

      var iterations = 1000;
      for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
      {
        var postParameters = new NameValueCollection();
        postParameters.Add("data", i.ToString());
        HttpSocket.PostAsync(url, postParameters, callbackState =>
          {
            if (callbackState.Exception != null)
              throw callbackState.Exception;
            Console.WriteLine(HttpSocket.GetResponseText(callbackState.ResponseStream));
          });
      }
```

Comment: What kind of example do you need?

Comment: As an example of the type of use?